# How to submit data to php class private variable using a drop down list

Tags: php, class

I have 2 MySQL tables having the same structure but containing different data. From the index page, using a drop-down list, I want to choose the table to connect to.

The table variable $empTable (which is the variable I want to change) is a private variable in a PHP class in **employee.php**.

I want to update the employee.php from the dropdown list on the index page without redirect. I can see the dropdown is working as I can echo the result, but I can't seem to get it to work w/the employee page.  Thanks for any and all help.

Here is the form on the index page:

```
<?php

$conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', '1601') 
or die ('Cannot connect to db');

    $result = $conn->query("SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM `information_schema`.`tables` WHERE table_schema = '1601'");
    
    echo "<html>";
    echo "<body>";
    echo "<form method='post' action=''>";
    echo "<select name='GetTableName' onchange='this.form.submit()' >";
    echo "<option selected='selected' value='select table'>select table</option>";

    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

                  unset($name);
                /*  $id = $row['id']; */
                  $name = $row['TABLE_NAME']; 
                  echo '<option value="'.trim($name).'">'.trim($name).'</option>';
                  
}

    echo "</select>";
    echo "</br>";
    echo "</form>"; 
    echo "</body>";
    echo "</html>";
    
   
?> 
<?php
$Tname = $_POST['GetTableName']; // so I can see this posting
    echo htmlspecialchars($Tname); // returns "array"

?>
```

Here is the employee page/the PHP class:

```
<?php

require('config.php');

class Employee extends Dbconfig {   
    protected $hostName;
    protected $userName;
    protected $password;
    protected $dbName;
    private   $empTable; //<== changed empTable value
    private $dbConnect = false;
    public function __construct(){
        if(!$this->dbConnect){      
            $database = new dbConfig();            
            $this -> hostName = $database -> serverName;
            $this -> userName = $database -> userName;
            $this -> password = $database ->password;
            $this -> dbName = $database -> dbName;          
            $conn = new mysqli($this->hostName, $this->userName, $this->password, $this->dbName);
            if($conn->connect_error){
                die("Error failed to connect to MySQL: " . $conn->connect_error);
            } else{
                $this->dbConnect = $conn;
            }
        }
    }
  // added function to update emptable
    
     public function setEmpTable(string $tableName)
        {
        $this->empTable = $tableName;
        }
   
    .....more functions
```

Dtable:

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
    var employeeData = $('#employeeList').DataTable({  //<---DT employeelist
        "lengthChange": false,
        "processing":true,
        "serverSide":true,
        "order":[],
        "ajax":{
            url:"action.php",
            type:"POST",
            data:{action:'listEmployee'},
            dataType:"json"
        },
        "columnDefs":[
            {
                "targets":[0,4,5],
                "orderable":false,
            },
        ],
        "pageLength": 10
    });
```

Action.php

```
<?php
include('Employee.php');
$emp = new Employee();
if(!empty($_POST['action']) && $_POST['action'] == 'listEmployee') {
    $emp->employeeList();  //<---loads the table w/ID listemployee
}
if(!empty($_POST['action']) && $_POST['action'] == 'addEmployee') {
    $emp->addEmployee();
}
if(!empty($_POST['action']) && $_POST['action'] == 'getEmployee') {
    $emp->getEmployee();
}
if(!empty($_POST['action']) && $_POST['action'] == 'updateEmployee') {
    $emp->updateEmployee();
}
if(!empty($_POST['action']) && $_POST['action'] == 'empDelete') {
    $emp->deleteEmployee();
}
?>
```

Comment: From what I understand, you have an index page which is using ajax to submit form data to employee.php. In employee.php, you define a class, but never initialize an object like `$em = new Employee();` so the constructor is never called. I'd start with adding that line to the bottom of the file and seeing where that gets you. Also, what is the purpose of `$Tname = $_POST['GetTableName'];` outputting after your closing HTML tag?

Comment: Why does Employee `extends Dbconfig` but also call `$database = new dbConfig();`? To clarify, those are 2 separate classes due to the capitalization of the names, right? It just seems confusing at first look.

Comment: Lastly, I'd probably move `$empTable = $_POST['GetTableName']` inside the constructor or a `setTableName()` function so you can do some extra validation of the POST data before blindly running a query with that value. Then define it at first as an empty string like `private $empTable = '';`

Comment: @WOUNDEDStevenJones hi, thanks for your comments.  Full disclosure: I modified this script from the wide web for my purposes, so .. I'm not as proficient in PHP as it might appear from the post I've provided. The purpose of $Tname = $_POST['GetTableName']; was just so I knew the drop down was working. There is another config class this class is referencing, it extends the original by adding tablename, so yes there are two classes.

Answer (score 0):

Expressions are not allowed as a class attribute default value. To fix this, change this line:

```php
    private   $empTable = $_POST['GetTableName'];<----change $empTable value
```

to:

```php
    private   $empTable;
```

Then create a method inside the `Employee` class to set the `$empTable` attribute:

```php
    public function setEmpTable(string $tableName)
    {
        $this->empTable = $tableName;
    }
```

Then, in your code that processes the request, you would call that method before running your queries:

```php
...
$emp = new Employee;
$emp->setEmpTable($_POST['GetTableName']);
...
```

Comment: thanks for your help.  Sorry the code I provided is not my own but modified to suit my purposes.  I'm not proficient in PHP.  I'm not sure where to insert the 
...
$emp = new Employee;
$emp->setEmpTable($_POST['GetTableName']);
...
I tried adding it at the top of the class, I don't have it working.

Comment: also tried adding into the ajax script
 `data: "$emp = new Employee; 
$emp->setEmpTable($_POST['GetTableName']);"`

Comment: it should go in `employee.php`, where the ajax request is being made. Can you show the contents of that file, so that I may help you with that?

Comment: @Scmidty Ok thanks I've provided the entire employee.php procedure.  I've included the changes you had suggested.

Comment: Okay thanks. The problem is that the `employee.php` file only declares the Employee class, but does nothing with it. I'm just now re-reading your question and see this line, and I think I understand a bit better: "I want to update the employee.php from the dropdown list on the index page without redirect. I can see the dropdown is working as I can echo the result, but I can't seem to get it to work w/the employee page".  So is there a separate Employee page where you want to see the changes?

Comment: I've included 2 more scripts which may help?  Sorry this maybe getting out of scope my apologies.  The 2 additional scripts load data into an html table on the index page.

Comment: Okay, I think I understand what you want here. The issue is that on the first page, where you are selecting which table to pull from, that selection isn't stored anywhere. Variables don't persist across separate sessions. You will need to include the dropdown of tables on the same page where DTable lives. Then when the call to "action.php" is made, you would pass in the 'GetTableName' parameter along with the action parameter. Then, call the `setEmpTable` method in the action.php file. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: @Scmidty Thanks for your help. Ok I made some progress (I think!!). If I hard code the `action.php` where $t2 is the tablename: `$t2='1601T' include('Employee.php'); $emp = new Employee(); if(!empty($_POST['action']) && $_POST['action'] == 'listEmployee') { $emp->setEmpTable($t2); $emp->employeeList();}` and the page loads and displays correctly. My challenge is how to submit to the page where DTables lives (data.js). The page is referenced from the index page as `<script src="js/data.js"></script>`. Thus I can't include it to submit to it if that makes sense.

Comment: I did try to submit to `action.php` using start_session and curl but was not able to grap the variable...I think you still have to access the page for either of these methods to work and this page isn't viewable.